# Pod is using node group role instead of service account in aws eks with an up to date AWS SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

my pods are using the node group role instead of the role defined by the service account. The service account configuration seems to be right because when I run `kubectl exec pod_name -- env | grep AWS` AWS_ROLE_ARN and AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE env variables are correct.

I'm using AWS Java sdk version 1.12.233 which should support service accounts. Still according to the logs of my app, the node group role is used. The cluster runs Kubernetes 1.22

Any idea what could be the matter?

Comment: Two things: what happens if you run `aws sts get-caller-identity` from within that Pod? also, if you dial up the logging verbosity for `software.amazon` does it say why it ignores the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity?

Comment: aws sts get-caller-identity returns the role defined in the service account. I can't change the logs right now, I'll give it a try tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the logs I found

```
c.a.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.log - Unable to load credentials
from WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles
the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path.
```

While looking for that message I found https://github.com/gkatzioura/CloudStorageMaven/issues/23 The solution in my case was to add aws-java-sdk-sts in the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same behaviour when I configured the trust policy not correctly. I used the Java AWS SDK 2 and when I checked identity it was falling back to node identity. I did not see this behaviour with docker image `amazon/aws-cli` that is a good way to test the Service Account according to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/associate-service-account-role.html).

My issue was caused by specifying the wrong oidc provider in the trust policy which should like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/id/<oidc-id>"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
        "Condition": {
          "StringLike": {
            "oidc.eks.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/id/<oidc-id>:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com",
            "oidc.eks.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/id/<oidc-id>:sub": "system:serviceaccount:*:*"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
}
```